# Add multiple xml files together in command line

Tags: python, xml, file, cmd, command-line

I have 300,000 xml files I need to put together as one big xml file. I know you can add csv files together by going to the directory with the files and then running this command:

copy *.csv combine.csv

Is there a simple way of combining xml files in command line?

Comment: write some code

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Try a web search for merging xml files and converting xml to csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do it. Best option will be to write a program that extracts the information from the tags and then puts it into a pandas dataframe which you can export as csv.